# react-native-toast-message add timer bar at bottom of message

Tags: react-native, toast

I would like to add a status bar timer for when the toast message will automatically go back into hide mode. I couldn't find anything in the docs, but I'm curious if anyone has been able to find something supported by the library that can do this?

## App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { Button, Pressable, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Toast from 'react-native-toast-message';
import { AntDesign, Ionicons as Icon } from '@expo/vector-icons';

// Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

const toastConfig = {
  success: ({ text1 }: any) => (
    <View
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: 60,
        width: '100%',
        paddingLeft: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#87b64f'
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: '#ffffff', fontSize: 20 }}>
        {text1}
        <Icon name="checkmark" size={24} color="#ffffff" />
      </Text>
      <Pressable
        style={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          width: 60,
          height: '100%',
          marginLeft: 'auto',
          borderLeftWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#ffffff'
        }}
        onPress={() => Toast.hide()}
      >
        <AntDesign name="close" size={24} color="#ffffff" />
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  ),
  error: ({ text1 }: any) => (
    <View
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: 60,
        width: '100%',
        paddingLeft: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#f27474'
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: '#ffffff', fontSize: 20 }}>{text1}</Text>
      <Pressable
        style={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          width: 60,
          height: '100%',
          marginLeft: 'auto',
          borderLeftWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#ffffff'
        }}
        onPress={() => Toast.hide()}
      >
        <AntDesign name="close" size={24} color="#ffffff" />
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  )
};

export default function App(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <View
      style={{ display: 'flex', paddingTop: 200, paddingHorizontal: 40, backgroundColor: '#ffffff', height: '100%' }}
    >
      <Button
        title="Show Toast"
        onPress={() =>
          Toast.show({
            topOffset: 0,
            type: 'success',
            text1: 'Success'
          })
        }
      />
      <Toast config={toastConfig} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

## Expected Result (Something like)

[image]

## Actual Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom layout for your toast as you need
you can find a full description [here](https://github.com/calintamas/react-native-toast-message/blob/main/docs/custom-layouts.md) on docs

I also created an example for you on [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@ahmedhamed70/thankful-violet-fudge) with a little progress bar at the bottom of the toast, you just need to modify it as you need you may use Animated from react-native or reanimated as you like

Comment: This did send me in the right direction, but I'm not able to see the progress bar in my device with your solution example. Also, inside your example the bar only shows once and then never again. I did get it to work with some code of my own, but it has another issue with overrendering to which I posted another quesiton here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77647473/toast-message-animated-progress-bar-exhaustive-deps