# Toast Message Animated Progress Bar Exhaustive-Deps

Tags: react-native, animation

After recently applying the `react-native-toast-message`. I wanted to add a progress bar at the bottom. I was able to do it, but typescript is warning me of over-rendering behavior. I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this.

Typescript warning: `The 'progress' object construction makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 15) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the initialization of 'progress' in its own useMemo() Hook.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Another thing I noticed is the `console.log('running:', progress)` happens around 4x per click.

[image]

## The Code

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Animated } from 'react-native';

export default function ProgressBar(): JSX.Element {
  const progress = new Animated.Value(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('running:', progress);
    Animated.timing(progress, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 2000,
      useNativeDriver: false
    }).start();
  }, [progress]);

  // render
  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        height: 4,
        width: progress.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: ['100%', '0%']
        }),
        backgroundColor: 'white', // Progress bar color
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

## The desired result

[image]